Asymptotics of a ratio on the unit sphere
Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a nonnegative, strictly decreasing sequence with $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Consider the ratio (for $k \geq n$)
$$
R_{n, k} = \mathbb{E}_{u \sim \text{Unif}(\mathbb{S}^{k-1})}
\Big[\frac{a_n u_n^2}{\sum_{m=1}^k a_m u_m^2} 
\Big].
$$
Is it possible to compute the limit
$$
R^\star_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} R_{n, k}?
$$

In the limit you consider, the coordinates become iid centered Gaussians.

Yes. The expectation of that will be the limit of your expectation as $k\to\infty$.

Perhaps a way to restate what you are saying is that (say by dominated convergence), $$ R_n^\star = \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{a_n g_n^2}{\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m g_m^2}\Big],$$ where the expectation is taken over the sequence ${g_m}_{m \geq 1}$ of iid standard Normals.
